# Bash: capture ping's intermediary statistics on SIGQUIT to variable

Tags: bash, ping, sigkill, output-redirect

I have this:

```
 ping -q xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx & disown; pingpid=$!
 for run in {1..3}; do
 sleep 5
 stats+=$(kill -SIGQUIT $pingpid)
 done
 kill $pingpid
```

So basically I launch ping in background with -q option (to show just stats), get its PID and then execute a `for` loop in which I want to store the intermediary stats of ping on each `kill -SIGQUIT $pingpid` in a variable... that's 3 lines of stats, 5 seconds apart.

I can see the intermediary stats being printed to stdout but when I check the `$stats` variable, I find it empty. I also tried with stderr redirection to stdout but I still can't get the variable to have the stats stored in it.

Comment: Good question... Looks like whatever prints as a result of the `kill -SIGQUIT` is not using a standard output stream. `>` and `2>` certainly perform no redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output that you're trying to capture is coming from the ping process (on it's standard error to be precise), not the kill process. You need to capture its output with a redirection when you launch it. Try this:

```
stats=""
{
        read pingpid
        for run in {1..3}; do
                sleep 5
                kill -quit $pingpid
                read line
                stats+="$line"$'\n'
        done
} < <(ping -q xx.xx.xx.xx 2>&1 >/dev/null & echo $!)

kill $pingpid
stats=${stats%$'\n'}  # Remove the extra newline
echo "$stats"
```

The ordering of the redirection in the `ping` command, `2>&1 >/dev/null`, redirects standard out to `/dev/null` while standard error is redirected to the input of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  It seems like you should actually be running `ping` with a timeout, or a limited number of packets (amounts to the same thing in the end).

```
for run in 1 2 3; do
    ping -c 5 -q 12.34.56.78 | tail -n 2
done
```

The regular output from `ping` is somewhat more verbose than the single line you get when you send it a SIGQUIT, so we need two lines of output.  Perhaps you want to pipe to some simple Awk script to normalize the output to make it fit your needs, or perhaps transform it to a properly machine-readable format.